# homepage only loading header and footer?

Tags: magento2, cms, home-page

I have created a new CMS page called "Homepage" and added some content to it. I have set this new CMS page as the CMS Homepage in Magento 2 admin. but when I go to the base URL I only get the Header and Footer and no homepage content. When I go to baseURL/homepage the content loads fine?

Why is this happening?

Comment: really strange .Suggest  check log

Comment: Might some code at cms_index_index.xml removing container section

Answer (score 1):

You need to select your new homepage in `CMS Home Page` dropdown under `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages`

For more details, go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/cms/pages-default.html